# Change the line height of all content in a Google doc using the API via nodejs using batchupdate()

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Using [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get) I can retrieve a document. The result is structured as described at [Resource: documents](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#Document).
However, I need to select the whole document and change the line-height to 1.5, but I am unable to find a way to do it.

```js
    var updateObject = {
      documentId: documentId,
      resource: {
        requests: [{
          'updateTextStyle': {
            'range': {
              'startIndex': 1,
              'endIndex': 0
            },
            'textStyle': {
              'line-height': 1.5
            },
            'fields': 'line-height'
          }
        }],
      },
    };
    docs.documents.batchUpdate(updateObject)
      .then(function(res) { // Modified
        console.log(res);
      }, function(err) {
        console.error(err);
      });
```

Comment: Where in the documentation does it say its possible to set the line hight?

Comment: It doesn't - which is the issue... that is "pseudo code"... I am now looking at attempting to do it using App scripts instead...

Answer (score 2):

- [Get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get) your document and [calculate start and end indexes](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/overview#locations_within_a_document_indexes) of all `paragraphs` within  the `body`.
- Issue [`updateParagraphStyle`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#UpdateParagraphStyleRequest) request for each of the above `paragraphs` with [`linespacing`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#ParagraphStyle) as `150` for 1.5 times the normal space.

Comment: Thanks, TheMaster - I am yet to check to see if this works as I went with the Google Apps Script version - but I am still keen to try it. I will let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this using Google Apps Script...

```
function setLineHeight() {
  var d = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var b = d.getBody()
  var pars = b.getParagraphs();
  // for each paragraph in the active document...
  pars.forEach(function(e) {
      // clean up paragraphs that only contain whitespace
      e.setLineSpacing(1.5);  
  })  
}
```