# Looking for a way to add borders to a paragraph in a google doc using a Google Apps Script or perhaps the DOCS API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

It is possible to add a border to a google doc paragraph via the **Format** menu > **Paragraph styles** > **Borders and shading**.

[image]

The result looks like this:

[image]

However, I have not managed to work out how to do this using Google Apps Scripts?

I have consulted the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setattributesattributes) concerning setting attributes, however, borders do no appear. It seems it is possible to set them using sheets and slides - but that isn't the use-case I am after.

I used the DOCS API via node.js to download the sample JSON returned from a document containing a border that I needed.

```
function printDocTitle(auth) {
  const documentId = '###';
  const docs = google.docs({version: 'v1', auth});
  docs.documents.get({
    documentId: documentId,
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const doc = res.data;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(doc, null, 4));
  })
}
```

The part of the JSON that represented the effect I wished to create looked like this.

```
{
  "startIndex": 82,
  "endIndex": 83,
  "paragraph": {
      "elements": [
          {
              "startIndex": 82,
              "endIndex": 83,
              "textRun": {
                  "content": "\n",
                  "textStyle": {
                      "fontSize": {
                          "magnitude": 12,
                          "unit": "PT"
                      },
                      "baselineOffset": "NONE"
                  }
              }
          }
      ],
      "paragraphStyle": {
          "namedStyleType": "NORMAL_TEXT",
          "alignment": "END",
          "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT",
          "borderBottom": {
              "color": {
                  "color": {
                      "rgbColor": {}
                  }
              },
              "width": {
                  "magnitude": 1.5,
                  "unit": "PT"
              },
              "padding": {
                  "magnitude": 1,
                  "unit": "PT"
              },
              "dashStyle": "SOLID"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I am wondering if I could somehow make use of that instead of using Google Scripts - but the DOCS API does not appear to support borders.

Would be grateful for any clues, hints or tips?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the line height of all content in a Google doc using the API via nodejs using batchupdate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394199/change-the-line-height-of-all-content-in-a-google-doc-using-the-api-via-nodejs-u)

Comment: Have you used the `DocumentApp.Attribute` enums? Check if my answer works for you.

Comment: I marked as duplicate because it's essentially the same `updateParagraphStyle` request in docs api.

Comment: Hello Master - it is not the same... they are different attributes? You can update the line-spacing in google app scripts - but you cannot add a border that I can see? So, this question is focussing on a property (border - not line-spacing) that you cannot update using Google Apps Scripts. And it does not appear to be in the DOC API. Unless you know something I don't - please can you share? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to add the border in Google Document using Google Docs API.
- You want to achieve this using Node.js and Google Apps Script.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Document with Google Docs API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

The border can be added by the batchUpdate method in Google Docs API. In this case, `UpdateParagraphStyleRequest` is used. For example, from the JSON object in your question, when the following parameter is used,

```
"paragraphStyle": {
    "namedStyleType": "NORMAL_TEXT",
    "alignment": "END",
    "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT",
    "borderBottom": {
        "color": {"color": {"rgbColor": {}}},
        "width": {"magnitude": 1.5, "unit": "PT"},
        "padding": {"magnitude": 1, "unit": "PT"},
        "dashStyle": "SOLID"
    }
}
```

The request body for the batchUpdate method is as follows. In this case, as the sample, the border is added to the top of Document using `{"startIndex": 1, "endIndex": 2}`.

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateParagraphStyle": {
        "paragraphStyle": {
          "namedStyleType": "NORMAL_TEXT",
          "alignment": "END",
          "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT",
          "borderBottom": {
            "width": {"magnitude": 1.5, "unit": "PT"},
            "padding": {"magnitude": 1, "unit": "PT"},
            "dashStyle": "SOLID"
          }
        },
        "range": {"startIndex": 1, "endIndex": 2},
        "fields": "namedStyleType,alignment,direction,borderBottom"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, Node.js is used.

#### Sample script:

When the following script is run, a border is added to the top of Google Document.

```
const documentId = "###";  // Please set the Document ID.

const docs = google.docs({ version: "v1", auth });
const requests = [
  {
    updateParagraphStyle: {
      paragraphStyle: {
        namedStyleType: "NORMAL_TEXT",
        alignment: "END",
        direction: "LEFT_TO_RIGHT",
        borderBottom: {
          width: { magnitude: 1.5, unit: "PT" },
          padding: { magnitude: 1, unit: "PT" },
          dashStyle: "SOLID"
        }
      },
      range: { startIndex: 1, endIndex: 2 },
      fields: "namedStyleType,alignment,direction,borderBottom"
    }
  }
];
docs.documents.batchUpdate(
  {
    documentId: documentId,
    requestBody: { requests }
  },
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(res.data);
  }
);
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, Google Apps Script is used. In this case, the above request body can be used without modifying.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Docs API at Advanced Google services.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

```
const documentId = "###";  // Please set the Document ID.
const requests = [
  {
    updateParagraphStyle: {
      paragraphStyle: {
        namedStyleType: "NORMAL_TEXT",
        alignment: "END",
        direction: "LEFT_TO_RIGHT",
        borderBottom: {
          width: { magnitude: 1.5, unit: "PT" },
          padding: { magnitude: 1, unit: "PT" },
          dashStyle: "SOLID"
        }
      },
      range: { startIndex: 1, endIndex: 2 },
      fields: "namedStyleType,alignment,direction,borderBottom"
    }
  }
];
const res = Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({requests}, documentId);
console.log(res);
```

- **In this case, please enable V8 runtime.**

### References:

- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateParagraphStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updateparagraphstylerequest)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: This answer actually led to a further question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60432342/get-the-ranges-of-the-elements-in-a-google-doc-using-google-apps-script

Comment: @Heartful Dodger Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I saw your new question. I could notice that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.